# Intent Chaining in ASK game

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating a game in ASK (Alexa Skills Kit) where a Alexa will ask the product between two random numbers in a range specified by the user. When the user answers, Alexa should tell them if the answer is correct or incorrect (UserAnswerIntentHandler), and then ask a new question (GamePlayIntentHandler).

```
const GamePlayIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'GamePlayIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput){
        
        const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;
        const attributes = await attributesManager.getSessionAttributes() || {};
        
        var lowestNum = attributes.lowestNum
        var highestNum = attributes.highestNum
        
        function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
    }
   
        var randomOne = getRandomIntInclusive(lowestNum, highestNum)
        var randomTwo = getRandomIntInclusive(lowestNum, highestNum)
        
        attributes.randomOne = randomOne
        attributes.randomTwo = randomTwo
        
        
        const speakOutput = `What is ${randomOne} times ${randomTwo}?` //Here, alexa is asking for the product between two random numbers in a range the user previously specified.
        
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .addElicitSlotDirective('answer', {
                name: 'UserAnswer',
                confirmationStatus: 'NONE'
            })
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(`Sorry, I didn't get that. What is ${randomOne} times ${randomTwo}?`)
            .getResponse(); 
    }
}

const UserAnswerIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'UserAnswerIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const {requestEnvelope} = handlerInput
        const {intent} = requestEnvelope.request
        
        const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;
        const attributes = await attributesManager.getSessionAttributes() || {};
        
        var userAnswer = parseInt(Alexa.getSlotValue(requestEnvelope, 'answer'))
        const randomOne = attributes.randomOne
        const randomTwo = attributes.randomTwo
        var correctAnswer = randomOne * randomTwo
        var points = 0
        var speakOutput = ""
        
        if (userAnswer > 0){
            if (userAnswer === correctAnswer){
                points +=1
                speakOutput = `That's correct! You now have ${points} points.`
                return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                    .speak(speakOutput)
                    .addDelegateDirective({
                        name: 'GamePlayIntent',
                        confirmationStatus: 'NONE'
                    })
                    .getResponse();
            }//If the answer is correct, the user gets a point and Alexa should immediatley ask the next question
            else{
                speakOutput = `Your answer is incorrect. The correct answer is ${correctAnswer}. You currently have ${points} points.`
                return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                    .speak(speakOutput)
                    .addDelegateDirective({
                        name: 'GamePlayIntent',
                        confirmationStatus: 'NONE'
                    })
                    .getResponse();
            }//If the answer is incorrect, Alexa will give the correct answer and total points and immediatley go to the next question
        }
    }
}
```

What's happening right now is that Alexa isn't telling the user if their answer is correct or incorrect, and is immediately asking the next question.
Is there any way to fix this or create a loop such that as soon as the user answers, Alexa can evaluate the answer, and then immediately ask the next question?

Answer (score 0):

When the `GamePlayIntent` is triggered, Alexa will ask a question then get the answer provided by the user.

The answer should then trigger UserAnswerIntent.

At this point, `UserAnswerIntentHandler` is triggered and goes to the `handle(handlerInput)` where you have your logic to verify the answer.

Once done, Alexa gives the correct answer then chain with the new question in the same message string.

You can build you string message by having one part for verifying the answer and a second part for the next question, you concatenate the strings together and return it in the same `responseBuilder .speak()`, followed by a repromt to make sure the user is giving an answer.

Once the user's input is captured, it will again triggered the corresponding intent to verify the new answer.

Another way would be to ask the user if they would like to have a new question through `YesIntent`/`NoIntent`.

If the answer is yes then you redirect them to the GamePlayIntent using

```
return GamePlayIntentHandler.handle(handlerInput);
```

If the answer is no then you add a goodbye message and close the session or so depending on the skill functionality/logic.

Here are some sample skills ([1](https://github.com/alexa-samples/alexa-guided-walkthrough-using-node-sdk/blob/master/part-2/index.js), [2](https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/blob/mainline/lambda/index.js)) I found that you can get guided by, one includes questions/answers handled in a different way.